# Split redux reducers based on auth flow

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I have an app where 2 types of accounts are possible: `User` and `Admin`. An admin cannot be a user and vice versa.

When writing the redux reducer, I cannot think of a way to split the reducer based on auth flow.

An admin can create surveys and a user can take them. There are no actions common to both type of accounts.

Currently, admin actions like, `CREATE_SURVEY`, `EDIT_SURVEY`, etc. lie alongside user actions, like `START_SURVEY`, `SUBMIT_SURVEY`, etc. in a single reducer file `reducer.js`.

Needless to say, I do **not** intend the user to see reducer logic for admin, and vice versa. How should I go about splitting the reducer for a basic auth flow?

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-action-reducer (otherwise, heaven forbid, I'd create seperate stores )

Comment: Can't you create two separate applications, one user application and one admin application?

Comment: @JonasBerlin. I'd prefer not to create 2 separate apps, since about 80% of the interface and functioning are same. The only differences are where resource creation/consumption take place.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?